# If the subset of the .NET framework is included in the Silverlight Plugin why does it not automtically work on Linux

Tags: silverlight

If the subset of the .NET framework is included in the Silverlight Plugin why does it not automtically work on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight) to run Silverlight applications on Linux

Comment: I know, its just this is a third party thing. I'm wondering why MS didn't target linux and if there were any technical reasons why not

Comment: @AJM: For the same reason they don't actively build the full .NET framework for Linux.  Its not in their interests to spread their development resources thinner to cover a platform that ultimately doesn't earn them any money.  They are a business after all.  Note also that in the desktop client arena Linux has a very, very small share compared with Macs and Windows combined.

Comment: This makes sense in terms of business. I'm just a bit hazy on the effort required to port the plugin to a different OS, I'm guessing it must be non trivial